# Can someone explain this?

Tags: relays, attacks

Can someone please explain this? still unfamiliar i mean this ip's looks suspicious is this a ddos attack?m new to relay operating so please explain thank you.

[image]

Comment: It's not DDOS, since those all come from one source IP. It's someone making lots of HTTP requests.